# Relation between conditional independence and conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be three random variables.

Are the following two related (for example, one implies the other):

- $Y$ and $Z$ are conditional independent on $X$
- $E(Y\mid X)$ and $E(Z\mid X)$ are independent?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $X$ an event or a random variable? From the first statement it seems to be an event, but in the second statement it is treated as a random variable.

Comment: $X$ is a random variable in both statements.

Comment: @Hoda : I think Tim got it right: $X$ is a random variable in both cases.  I see no reason to assume $X$ is an event in the first bulleted statement.

Comment: That's right, it was a confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one certainly comes nowhere near implying the second.  For example, suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and $Y$ is $1$ or $0$ with probabilities $X$ and $1-X$, and $Z$ is $1$ or $0$ with those same probabilities, and they're conditionally independent given $X$.  Then $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=\mathbb E(Z\mid X)=X$, so those are certainly not independent.

Maybe I'll post more later . . .

Comment: Thanks! What do you plan to post for more?

Comment: Also, based on your reply, I now realized I used "conditional independence" wrongly in [a previous post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/318709/1281), to which you also replied.

Comment: @Tim : Perhaps other examples.  Maybe one where $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)$ and $\mathbb E(Z\mid X)$ _are_ independent (although both determined by $X$) and where $X$ and $Y$ are _not_ conditionally independent given $X$.

Comment: looking forward to such examples.